# What is the Quota of created folders per day?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have checked quota of number of action per day like creating document and spread and etc.... at [Google Quota](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard)  , but didn't find limits for Folder creation and when I run the script for creating hundreds of folder it stopped after a while alerting me that I have exceed my limitation per day, So What is the Quota of created folders per day ?

Anther question : How by script I get number of limits per day, Is it coming from this below code

```
  DocsList.DEFAULT_RESULT_SIZE;
  DocsList.MAX_RESULT_SIZE;
```

Anther Question : How to get driveWriteVolume rateMax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google doesnt publish that quota as well as many others mainly because they are meant to reduce abuse and publishing them could help the abuse.
There is no api to get the published ones either.
Basically from apps script you should do a user's worth of work. I have a script that can create over 200 folders but havent tried it with more.

Comment: Thanks Zig, My script creates more than 300 Folders may be more than that with anther hundreds